# Search page slowed by large number of objects in Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

My Vue app has a search page where a user enters a query and gets back publication data related to the query from the backend. The publication data is stored in objects within my Vuex store and each publication in the store is shown on the search page.

My issue is that once a user searches for the first time and gets back their results (300+ search results on avg), the typing of the second search query is super slow. I know that the problem is related to the number of objects in my store because I don't have the issue whenever a really unique search query is used for the first search and fewer results are returned.

It seems weird to me that the application would get bogged down by that much data. Are there any best practices/tips on keeping your application running smoothly while storing a bunch of data in your Vuex state? New to Vue, so any advice would be helpful.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import user from './Modules/user.js'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

import { fetchReviewersBySearch, } from '../api/index.js'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    currentSearchReviewers: [],
    aPublications: {},
    bPublications: {},
    cPublications: {},
    dPublications: {},
    ePublications: {},
    ePublications: [],
    fPublications: {},
    fReviewers: [],
    dReviewers: [],
    aReviewers: [],
    bReviewers: [],
    cReviewers: [],
  },
  actions: {
    getReviewersBySearch (context, { searchQuery }) {
      return fetchReviewersBySearch(searchQuery)
        .then((response) => context.commit('setSearchReviewers', { reviewers: response.data }))
    },
  modules: {
    user
  },
  plugins: [createPersistedState()],
  mutations: {
    setSearchReviewers (state, payload) {
        // Payload data is a mix publication and reviewer data.
        // If publication data, puts into correct object based on publication type.
      if (payload.reviewers.a_publications) {
        state.aPublications = Object.assign(payload.reviewers.a_publications)
        delete payload.reviewers.a_publications
      }
      if (payload.reviewers.b_publications) {
        state.bPublications = Object.assign(payload.reviewers.b_publications)
        delete payload.reviewers.b_publications
      }
      if (payload.reviewers.c_publications) {
        state.cPublications = Object.assign(payload.reviewers.c_publications)
        delete payload.reviewers.c_publications
      }
      if (payload.reviewers.d_publications) {
        state.dPublications = Object.assign(payload.reviewers.d_publications)
        delete payload.reviewers.d_publications
      }
      if (payload.reviewers.e_publications) {
        state.ePublications = Object.assign(payload.reviewers.e_publications)
        delete payload.reviewers.e_publications
      }
      if (payload.reviewers.f_publications) {
        state.fPublications = Object.assign(payload.reviewers.f_publications)
        delete payload.reviewers.f_publications
      }
        //For the reviewer data within the payload, adds each reviewer to an array matching their corresponding publications   
      for (const entry in payload.reviewers) {
        if (payload.reviewers[entry].a_id) {
          state.aReviewers.push(payload.reviewers[entry])
        }
        if (payload.reviewers[entry].c_id) {
          state.cReviewers.push(payload.reviewers[entry])
        }
        if (payload.reviewers[entry].b_id) {
          state.bReviewers.push(payload.reviewers[entry])
        }
        if (payload.reviewers[entry].d_id) {
          state.dReviewers.push(payload.reviewers[entry])
        }
        if (payload.reviewers[entry].e_id) {
          state.ePublications.push(payload.reviewers[entry])
        }
        if (payload.reviewers[entry].f_id) {
          state.fReviewers.push(payload.reviewers[entry])
        }
      }
      // Sorts the reviewer arrays based on the number of publications associated with each reviewer.
      state.aReviewers.sort(function (a, b) { return b.publications.length - a.publications.length })
      state.bReviewers.sort(function (a, b) { return b.publications.length - a.publications.length })
      state.cReviewers.sort(function (a, b) { return b.publications.length - a.publications.length })
      state.dReviewers.sort(function (a, b) { return b.publications.length - a.publications.length })
      state.ePublications.sort(function (a, b) { return b.publications.length - a.publications.length })
      state.fReviewers.sort(function (a, b) { return b.publications.length - a.publications.length })
      
      //Keeps the top 50 reviewers of each publication type
      if (state.aReviewers.length > 50) {
        state.aReviewers.length = 50
      }
      if (state.bReviewers.length > 50) {
        state.bReviewers.length = 50
      }
      if (state.cReviewers.length > 50) {
        state.cReviewers.length = 50
      }
      if (state.peregrineReviewers.length > 50) {
        state.cReviewers.length = 50
      }
      if (state.dReviewers.length > 50) {
        state.dReviewers.length = 50
      }
      if (state.ePublications.length > 50) {
        state.ePublications.length = 50
      }
      if (state.fReviewers.length > 50) {
        state.fReviewers.length = 50
      }
      //Combines all the reviewer arrays into one and then empties the publication-specific arrays 
      state.currentSearchReviewers = state.aReviewers.concat(state.bReviewers, state.cReviewers, state.dReviewers, state.eReviewers, state.fReviewers)
      state.aReviewers = []
      state.bReviewers = []
      state.cReviewers = []
      state.dReviewers = []
      state.eReviewers = []
      state.fReviewers = []
    }
  }
}
})
```

### **Edit: Typical Data Flow**

A user will enter a search query which then gets passed to the backend where I have a couple of functions that call different APIs to return a json object that contains all the search results.

The json object key/value pairs are either related to one of six publications (a,b,c,d,e,f) or the reviewers corresponding to those publications. While there are only six key/value pairs corresponding to the publications (one for each), there can be up to 200-300 reviewer key/value pairs per publication.  So as an example, one json object will contain six publication key/value pairs and 600 total reviewer key/value pairs (100 per publication).

After getting this json object, the setSearchReviewers mutation occurs. In the mutation, I'm first taking the 6 publication key/value pairs from the json object, putting them into the state, and then deleting them from the json. Then I'm iterating through and putting each reviewer key/value pair into arrays corresponding to their publication.

After all the reviewers have been put into the right arrays, they are then sorted based on specific property values of the reviewers. Once the sorting is done, the arrays are modified so that only the top 50 results are kept for each array. Lastly, all arrays are combined into one big array to be displayed as the search results.

Comment: "_Are there any best practices/tips_" - Yes, there are, but those practices are based upon the code that creates the performance issue in the first place. No one will be able to assist you accurately without some idea of what you app code looks like.

Comment: Part (or whole) of the problem may be due to the number of publication and reviewer objects in your store, as well as all of the mutators calling Object.assign.  Might help to explain your design and give typical data/search flow example.

Comment: @Tim added the data flow below the code. Let me know if you need more info!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the slowdown was because I was rendering UI elements for all of the hundreds of search results on the page at the same. When I reduced the number of UI elements (without changing anything about the data in the store), the search page didn't slow down.

To fix this problem, all I did was add a pagination element to only render 10 results on the page at any given time.